# How to set custom columns sorting function to the gantt

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, gantt-chart

Isn't it possible to set custom columns sorting function to the gantt?
I didn't see it anywhere in [the documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/gantt/sorting/) 
We need to sort based on other criteria than the alphabetic order

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query and we are able to sort custom column with a different type of value (e.g., string, numeric). We can also do an initial sort using `sortSettings`, or dynamic sorting using `sortColumn` on custom column.

Please find the below code snippet.

```
[data.js]
exports.editingData = [
    {
        TaskID: 1,
        TaskName: 'Project initiation',
        StartDate: new Date('04/02/2019'),
        EndDate: new Date('04/21/2019'),
        subtasks: [
            {
                TaskID: 2, TaskName: 'Identify site location', StartDate: new Date('04/02/2019'), Duration: 0,
                Progress: 30, resources: [1], info: 'Measure the total property area alloted for construction', /*CustomColumn: 'BCustomColumn'*/ CustomColumn: '2'
            },
            {
                TaskID: 3, TaskName: 'Perform Soil test', StartDate: new Date('04/02/2019'), Duration: 4, Predecessor: '2',
                resources: [2, 3, 5], info: 'Obtain an engineered soil test of lot where construction is planned.' +
                    'From an engineer or company specializing in soil testing', /*CustomColumn: 'CCustomColumn2'*/ CustomColumn: '3'
            },
            { TaskID: 4, TaskName: 'Soil test approval', StartDate: new Date('04/02/2019'), Duration: 0, Predecessor: '3', Progress: 30, /*CustomColumn: 'ACustomColumn3'*/ CustomColumn: '1'},
        ]
    },
]
[index.js]
export class Sorting extends SampleBase {
…./////
        // this.sortSettings = {
        //     columns: [{ field: 'CustomColumn', direction: 'Ascending' }]
        // };
    }
    sortColumn() {
        this.ganttInstance.sortModule.sortColumn('CustomColumn', 'Ascending', false);
    }
    render() {
        return (<div className='control-pane'>
        <div className='control-section'>
          <ButtonComponent onClick={this.sortColumn.bind(this)}> Sort Custom Column </ButtonComponent>
          <GanttComponent id='Sorting' ref={gantt => this.ganttInstance = gantt} sortSettings={this.sortSettings} allowSorting={true}>
            <ColumnsDirective>
              <ColumnDirective field='CustomColumn'></ColumnDirective>
            </ColumnsDirective>
          </GanttComponent>
        </div>
      </div>);
    }
}
```

We have prepared sample for your reference. Please refer the below sample link.

**Sample link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xrwzdv?file=index.js